# Fair test of computational cost of log vs. sqrt

Tags: r, performance, complexity-theory, arithmetic-expressions

What's a fair way to assess whether it is better to log transform or square root transform data, assuming that for analytical purposes I am able to use either? In particular, **I am trying to understand whether in R it matters if I choose to apply `log` or `sqrt` to transform data, and if so whether it depends on the nature of the data, its overall size etc**.

Here's the code I initially used:

```
start.time = Sys.time()
for (x in 1:10000)
  log(x)
end.time = Sys.time()
print(end.time - start.time)

start.time = Sys.time()
for (x in 1:10000)
  sqrt(x)
end.time = Sys.time()
print(end.time - start.time)
```

However, then I started wondering if it depended on the nature of the data, so I tried variations, such as making the values larger or less dense:

```
start.time = Sys.time()
for (x in 1:10000000)
  log(x^8)
end.time = Sys.time()
print(end.time - start.time)

start.time = Sys.time()
for (x in 1:10000000)
  sqrt(x^8)
end.time = Sys.time()
print(end.time - start.time)
```

In the cases I tried, `sqrt` was always slightly faster than `log`, but I have no experience with testing efficiency/complexity and wonder **if there is a 'proper' way to answer this question (1) for R in particular (docs?) and (2) more generally?**

For example, I wonder if some of the failings of what I tried above are:

- Using integers (could answer be different for floats)
- Using a monotonic dense sequence?

**My most general question is what matters for making the assessment, and what would I need to know about R or my hardware to ask this question in an intelligent manner?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use a benchmarking package. R has a few of them. I recommend `microbenchmark`. Read its documentation for some ideas on benchmarking.

Play around. Don't take optimization too seriously. Always factor in the intellectual overhead of having to think about it.

For example:

```
library(microbenchmark)
x <- (1:1e6)^8
y <- runif(1e6)
z <- sort(y)
microbenchmark(log(x), sqrt(x), log(y), sqrt(y), log(z), sqrt(z), times=10)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>   log(x) 45.778425 46.21116 46.46333 46.40788 46.90995 46.99119    10  b 
#>  sqrt(x)  9.576967 11.30364 11.97100 11.99424 12.39120 16.09995    10 a  
#>   log(y) 58.630950 60.16966 60.68071 60.67257 61.53909 62.02924    10   c
#>  sqrt(y)  9.557819 11.09652 15.95161 11.97811 12.42969 55.37263    10 a  
#>   log(z) 46.039493 46.17527 46.34378 46.33622 46.43773 46.81620    10  b 
#>  sqrt(z) 11.111878 11.15454 11.77100 11.61037 12.35596 12.43116    10 a
```

Comment: *"Don't take optimization too seriously."* This alone deserves the upvote.

Comment: I do not disagree with this advice, but I suppose I am wondering if there are any rules of thumb to be aware of. Thank you for the package recommendation!

Comment: In R I would say you shouldn't worry about basic things like mathematical functions and so on. Knowledgeable people have done a good job implementing them. What you need to take care of is in the algorithms you develop yourself. The main rule of thumb in R is: try not to grow objects dynamically (e.g. with statements like `x <- c(x, new_val)` inside a loop. Otherwise it depends on the situation. Bad algorithms are going to be bad in most languages.